# How to spread arguments if the input is an array of arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Trying to spread an array as arguments into the `join` method on `path` in node, but no luck:

```
var path = require("path");
var paths = [__dirname];
var userInput = ["app", "js"];
paths.push(userInput);
var target = path.join.apply(null, paths);
```

I get:

> TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings

One possible solution is just give the method a string of arguments. I don't even know if that's possible. But just curious if there is a trick in JavaScript in situations like this. Or am I approaching it totally wrong ?

Comment: I don't get this error. Is this your actual code?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Can't repro either (Node v0.12)

Comment: I am reading values from the user with `inquirer`. Maybe I should rethink what I get from the user. I get path values like "app/js" and then split it into an array. And then I pass it to `path.join` to construct the path if that makes sense.

Comment: I will double check. Maybe I am doing something wrong with the input. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Using inquirer is an important detail. Please mention that and include the code that uses it.

Comment: The input array wasn't flattened. That was the problem.

Comment: You are pushing an array onto an array. Push its elements instead--you could use `concat`.

Comment: I knew I was over thinking it. Thanks!

Comment: You should post an answer and self-accept after a couple days, when you can.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are pushing an array onto an array, resulting in

```
[ __dirname, [ 'app', 'js' ] ]
```

`path.join` has no idea what to do with these nested arrays. `apply` does not somehow magically flatten its input. The error message from `path.join` could not be clearer: it wants its arguments to be strings, not arrays. So instead use `concat` to combine the arrays:

```
var path = require("path");
var paths = [__dirname];
var userInput = ["app", "js"];

// Use concat here
paths = paths.concat(userInput);

var target = path.join.apply(null, paths);
```

An alternative would be

```
paths.push.apply(paths, userInput);
```

which would push the elements of `userInput` onto `paths` one by one.

If you are using ES6, then you could use the spread operator and write this as:

```
paths.push(...userInput)
```

or

```
paths = [...paths, ...userInput]
```

or just directly

```
var target = path.join(...paths, ...userInput)
```

Comment: ES6 syntax is much more expressive!

Answer (score 1):

Actually the issue was that I was overthinking the problem. Instead of concatenating the paths array with the other array, I was pushing an array into the paths array:

```
var path = require("path");
var paths = [__dirname];
var userInput = ["app", "js"];
paths.push(userInput); // x
```

The problem can be avoided by just `paths.concat(userInput)`. Then you can spread the arguments:

```
path.join.apply(null, paths.concat(userInput));
```

Thanks to @torazaburo for pointing it out.